# Algorithm for finding all possible key combinations in given range

Tags: brute-force

Last time I got curious about how long would it take to break my password using brute force attack. I'd like to check it.

**So, how should I implement algorithm to find all possible key combinations in given range** (for eg. 15 letters)? I found algorithms for permutations around but they all swap letters for given word, it's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that passwords can consist of combinations of 89 possible characters (a-z, A-z, 0-9, space, and all the different symbol keys on a Windows keyboard), a there there are 82 the the 15th power different combinations of 15 characters (82 * 82 * 82 ... ).   In other words, a lot.

If you want to use just letters, and you differentiate between upper and lower case, there would be 52 ** 15 possible 15-letter combinations.   If you want to take  in the possibility of shorter strings as well you could write something like (pseudocode):

```
  long combos = 0

  for i = 6 TO 20           -- legal password lengths
     combos = combos + POW(52, i)

  print "there are " + combos.ToString() 
        + " possible passwords between 6 and 20 characters"
```

To actually enumerate and print the permutations in C# you could do:

```
  void AddNextCharAndPrintIfDone(string pwd, int maxLen)
  {
     for (char c = 'a';  c < 'Z';  c++)
     {
        pwd = pwd + c;
        if (pwd.Length >= maxLen)
            System.Console.WriteLine(pwd);
        else AddNextCharAndPrintIfDone(pwd, maxLen)
     }
  }

  Main()
  {
     for (int i=6;  i < 20;  i++)
           AddNextCharAndPrintIfDone("", i);
  }
```

Not really written for efficiency, but if you have enough memory and time, you'll get every possible permutation.

Comment: I want algorihtm to return those combinations, not to count them ;)

Comment: @MichałTabor You don't have the time, or computer memory to do the calculation.   I did a quick project to count the permutations, and came up with: 7,664,255,028,754,501,632.   If you calculated a million passwords per second, this would take 243,032 *years* to run through all the possibilities.    Just for the exercise, I'll add the algorithm to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can download php pear project math combinatoric to generate those passwords.